# How can Sweave users collaborate with Word users?

Tags: r, ms-word, sweave

I'd like to pitch the question discussed [here](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/help/12/04/9772.html) to the SO community: what is the best way for Sweave users to collaborate with Word users?

I'm trying to move my entire workflow to R and Sweave (or similar, e.g. maybe Knitr will prove more useful). However, the last step in my workflow is usually to write a manuscript with collaborators. They work by passing MS Word documents back and forth, and editing text using Track Changes.

Let's stipulate that I can't convince any of them to learn any new software - their process isn't going to change. I am looking for a straightforward way to:

1.) send Sweave-created documents to coauthors

2.) allow them to open the documents in Word and make tracked changes

3.) receive the edited documents and reincorporate them into Sweave, ideally with co-authors' changes highlighted in some way

4.) And if the solution works for OSX, that would be great.

The discussion [on the R help mailing list](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/help/12/04/9772.html) focusses on [SWord](http://rcom.univie.ac.at/) which appears to be undocumented and available only for Windows. Does anyone know if it is good? The discussion [on Vanderbilt's biostatistics wiki](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/SweaveConvert) is good on ways to get Sweave documents into Word-readable forms, but no so much on how to integrate edited Word documents with Sweave.

Comment: Do they have to use track changes? How about annotating the PDF? Or, you can separate the document and use the `\input` to recombine. There are related questions on tex.se, especially http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/workflow-for-converting-latex-into-open-office-ms-word-format, but also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/what-is-the-best-way-to-track-changes-with-non-computer-people,

Comment: I might be able to talk them into annotating the PDF (do you know if Adobe Reader can do this, or do you need the full Acrobat?)... thanks for the links.

Comment: Acrobat reader allows comment bubbles. [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) allows more comprehensive commenting.

Comment: Hey @DrewSteen I would think that since Sweave just makes a .tex file in the end that any of the methods for collaborating across LaTeX and Word would work... so you might want to check this question out too http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/what-is-a-good-strategy-for-obtaining-comments-on-a-latex-document-from-non-late/18694#18694

Comment: @DQdlM - that link is useful, but it seems like elegantly incorporating the tracked changes from Word back into the Sweave document is the trickier part.

Comment: Mmhh...why always close these how-to-convert-tex-to-word questions? I feel that Stack Exchange is against finding a solution for this problem. I have tried to solve this issue for 3 years now. The best way I have found is to convert the pdf to a word document using Nitro Pro 8. You can download the trial version and see if it works for you, but for my complicated documents it works very well. It keeps the formatting almost the same than in pdf and does not paste lines on separate lines as many pdf to word converters do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a combination of approaches, depending on who is editing. My default is to have editors / collaborators markup a PDF or hard copy.  [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) is free and provides more extensive PDF commenting tools than Acrobat reader, although reader allows comment bubbles.

For more extensive contributions, it helps that I separate out the Sweave parts of a document from the main text, e.g. by writing results in results.Rnw and the inserting `\input{results.tex}` into the main document. This allows you to send around the part that does not include the R markup. You can also copy-paste everything between the preamble and bibliography into a word document, and ask users to ignore the markup. If you copy-paste from an editor with syntax highlighting, it can be copied to word, making the process easier.

You might also consider using [Inference for R](http://inferenceforr.com/default.aspx), which is like Sweave for Word. There is also [Lyx](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyxWithRThroughSweave), which requires users to learn a new program, but which is easier to use than Sweave.

Comment: Inference for R is more or less abandoned. Last reference is to R 2.9

Comment: @DieterMenne I see. [RWordXML](https://github.com/duncantl/RWordXML) appears to provide similar functionality, as described by [Nolan, Temple, and Lang](http://www.springerlink.com/content/x15332x6j00q7310/fulltext.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

I've always thought that this was a good use case for odfWeave....

Answer (score 2):

I've been researching on the issue for a couple of weeks now, and here is what I have come up with so far. Unfortunately, my newbie reputation does not allow to post all the proper links, but Google search should be evident for all the packages involved.

Conversions between LaTeX and Word are cumbersome, therefore I consider it feasible to use a third format which allows export to both LaTeX and Word. Several alternatives are available. First, you have Markdown, a markup language which I am using even to write this post :). Markdown in itself is not really suited for academic writing, but there is an [extension](http://mandown.rubyforge.org/) in development that allows for citations, footnotes and other features of technical writing.

Second, perhaps more promising, the reStructuredText markup from Docutils, which can handle citations already. My idea is to write my articles in plain text using reST, weaving (or knitting) them using knitr into HTML or PDF, this is supported natively from within R. R code can be embedded of course, that is the whole point.

To convert the text to .doc one can use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which can also handle citations, and is able to convert between multiple document formats, including PDF, Word, OpenDocument etc.

I still have to figure the whole workflow out. Converting between formats without the citations seems pretty straightforward to me (even though it requires some minor editing in Word afterwards). Working with citations still requires some figuring out. Hope this information helps whoever is on the same path of Reproducible Research, but also in the need to share texts with non-geek population.